# How to find words on both sides of (period)

Tags: regex, vb.net

in the following examples I need to get the words on either side on the period

I am using this regex

```
Dim myRegex As New Regex("[^\w]+")
Dim mymatch As String() = myRegex.Split(currentField)
```

where as currentfield = one of the following 3 samples

```
  Contacts.Address2 as `Contact Address2`
Contacts.ContactID
CONCAT(Contacts.FirstName;;' ';;Contacts.LastName) as `Contact`
```

returns are as follows.

1-- Contacts, Address2, as, Contact and Address2  do not want the word as.

2-- Contacts and ContactID    this is ok.

3-- CONCAT,Contacts,FirstName,Contacts,LastName,as and Contact.

3rd one this is too much do not want CONCAT,as or Contact. I only want the four words (ones before and after the period) to be returned Contacts, Firstname, Contacts, and Lastname

how can I write the regex to only get words before and after the period

Comment: Could you please explain what the 3rd output should be like and why? Right now, you split by non-word characters (actually, `\W+`).

Comment: The sample provided is not supported by the the description of your issue. Can you share more code and update up the language for better understanding?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you going to do with the strings you pull out?

Comment: the 3 lines I provided are strings I am pulling from a database and they represent the way a field was presented.  the words that are like xxxx.yyyy is the table name and column I need that separated and don't care what else is in the line hence only needing the words before and after the period so I can use the table and column that are listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider matching vs. `split`ting the input:

```
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, "(\w+)\.(\w+)")
    Console.WriteLine(
           String.Join(", ", 
                       m.Groups(1).Value,
                       m.Groups(2).Value
                      ))
Next
```

This is an example, It's not clear what you expect to do with the returned results.

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/v08v94)

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for, works perfect for all 3 scenarios I posted. the full sub is posted below that is using it,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to only split inside round brackets and you are not interested in the word `as`. Thus, I suggest a 2 step approach:

1. Get the substring(s) in round brackets (`\([^()]+\)` regex)
2. If there are such substrings, split them with the split regex, if not, split the original string with split regex (`\W+|\s*\bas\b\s*` regex).

[Sample code](http://ideone.com/1keLrv):

```
'Dim currentField As String = "Contacts.Address2 as `Contact Address2`"
Dim currentField As String = "CONCAT(Contacts.FirstName;;' ';;Contacts.LastName) as `Contact`"
'Dim currentField As String = "Contacts.ContactID"
Dim myRegex As New Regex("\([^()]+\)")
Dim splitRegex As New Regex("\W+|\s*\bas\b\s*")
Dim mymatch As MatchCollection = myRegex.Matches(currentField)
If mymatch.Count > 0 Then
    For Each match As Match In mymatch
        Dim mysubstrs As String() = splitRegex.Split(match.Value)
        For Each substr As String In mysubstrs
           If String.IsNullOrEmpty(substr) = False Then
                Console.WriteLine(substr)
           End If
        Next
    Next
Else
    Dim mysubstrs As String() = splitRegex.Split(currentField)
        For Each substr As String In mysubstrs
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(substr) = False Then
               Console.WriteLine(substr)
            End If
        Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the final working routine, based on the accepted answer above

```
Public Sub Load_Field_List(FieldSTR As String, FieldType As String)
        Dim t As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(New System.IO.StringReader(FieldSTR))
        t.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        t.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim ColListSTR As String = loadeddataview.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ColumnList")
        Dim ColListSTRArr As String() = ColListSTR.Split(",")
        While Not t.EndOfData

            Try
                currentRow = t.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String 'field string
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    Dim startName As Integer
                    Dim endName As Integer
                    Dim name As String
                    dr = fieldDT.NewRow
                    Dim isValid As Boolean = False
                    If currentField = "" Then  'make sure current field has data
                        isValid = False
                    ElseIf (Regex.IsMatch(currentField, "(\w+)\.(\w+)")) = True Then 'make sure current field has xxxx.yyyy pattern
                        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(currentField, "(\w+)\.(\w+)")    'sets m to the first xxxx.yyyy pattern
                        dr("Table") = m.Groups(1).Value                                 'sets table column to table name xxxx
                        dr("Column Name") = "`" & m.Groups(2).Value & "`"               'sets column name to column yyyy enclosed in ` `
                        If ColListSTRArr.Contains(m.Groups(2).Value) Then               'checks columnlist str to see if column visible
                            dr("Show") = "True"
                        Else
                            dr("Show") = "False"
                        End If

                        ' this section overrides column name if it was set using AS `zzzzz` statement
                        startName = currentField.IndexOf("`")
                        endName = currentField.IndexOf("`", If(startName > 0, startName + 1, 0))
                        If (endName > startName) Then
                            Dim mylength As Integer = currentField.Length
                            name = currentField.Substring(startName, endName - startName + 1)
                            dr("Column Name") = name                                            'set override columname
                            dr("Field") = currentField.Substring(0, startName - 4)              'sets field minus the " as 'ZZZZZ" above
                            If ColListSTRArr.Contains(currentField.Substring(startName + 1, endName - startName - 1)) Then    'dup may be able to remove
                                dr("Show") = "True"
                            Else
                                dr("Show") = "False"
                            End If
                        Else
                            dr("Field") = currentField                                              'sets field if there was no " as `ZZZZZZ`" in string
                        End If
                        If FieldType = "Field" Then                                                 'sets the column linking field
                            dr("Linking") = "No Linking"
                        Else
                            dr("Linking") = FieldType
                        End If
                    End If
                    ' commit changes
                    fieldDT.Rows.Add(dr)
                    fieldDT.AcceptChanges()
                    DataGridView3.DataSource = fieldDT
                    DataGridView3.ClearSelection()

                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                        FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While

    End Sub
```